# python list getting element in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the only element in a python list of dictionary.
If I do:

```
{{k.value}}
```

I get

```
[{'value_type': 2L, 'value_as_double': 74.0}]
```

How do I get just the 74?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `{{ k.value.0.value_as_double }}`.